# Is it bad practice to start a line with 'of'?

Tags: creative-writing, poetry

I have written a poem in which several lines begin with the word "of":

> The men and women
>
> Of the United States
>
> Who sang and danced along
>
> The music that echoed in the night
>
> Were drunk with joy
>
> The dancing twigs
>
> Of the old trees that
>
> Sang along with the birds
>
> Disappeared into the night
>
> And the men and women
>
> Of the United States
>
> Walked towards the sea

Is this okay, and why? And is there any situation where you would personally avoid it, and why?

Comment: It's poetry. You can basically do whatever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, that "of" doesn't start a verse, but a line.  Breaking a line in the midst of a grammatical unit is so common that it has a name -- [enjambment](https://literarydevices.net/enjambment/) -- and so does the situation where the unit and lines match -- end-stop.

Of opening a verse (or sentence) with a preposition such as "of", we can only say that the grammatical structure is valid though unusual and may serve stylistic purposes even in prose.

Comment: Bonus points for the stylish demonstration!